# How can I set a RatingBar clickable, but not scaleable?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I want to show an `AlertDialog` at clicking my `RatingBar`, but it the problem is that the `RatingBar` is still scaleable(Changing the rating is still possible).

I want that I can click the `RatingBar`, but not scale it.

In this case

```
<RatingBar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                    android:isIndicator="false"
                    android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
                    android:rating="5"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/showrating"
                    />
```

clicking the `RatingBar` is possible, but scaling too.

In this case

```
<RatingBar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                    android:isIndicator="true"
                    android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
                    android:rating="5"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/showrating"
                    />
```

scaling is not possible, but clicking is not possible too.

> In both cases I don't reach what I want.

#### I've got a problem with `android:isIndicator=""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is wrap your RatingBar in a FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="onClick">
        <RatingBar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                    android:isIndicator="true"
                    android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
                    android:rating="5"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/showrating"
                    />
</FrameLayout>
```

then put the AlertDialogue logic in the onClick method:

```
public void onClick(View v){
        //AlertDialogue Logic
}
```

Comment: Do I have do add the onclick to the frame layout or to the RatingBar?

Comment: @Jakob To the FrameLayout.

Comment: Thank you :) It works. Please vote my question up, if you think I asked well.